# How to enable PCRE2 in vscode 1.49?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to enable PCRE2 for search and replace in VScode as suggested in https://dev.to/rfornal/vs-code-search-and-replace-regex-mn2 but when I search for such an option via settings, I cannot (and VSCode does not give any result) for the enabling of this feature.

My setup is:

```
Version: 1.49.1 (system setup)
Commit: 58bb7b2331731bf72587010e943852e13e6fd3cf
Date: 2020-09-16T23:27:51.792Z
Electron: 9.2.1
Chrome: 83.0.4103.122
Node.js: 12.14.1
V8: 8.3.110.13-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18363
```

The post is relatively current, 16 de set. de 2019, so I surmise still is current information.

Is this a setting that can only be changed via editing of the .json file?

Comment: because the regex to use is a JavaScript Regex, it supports back references and look arounds, that article was written a year ago, most likely they have removed the setting

Comment: Relevant: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_37#_search-regex-features

Answer (score 4):

from: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_37

## Search regex features

Back in the 1.29 release, we added the setting search.usePCRE2 to make search use the PCRE2 regex engine. This enabled searching with some advanced regex features such as backreferences and lookahead assertions. Thanks to some upstream work in ripgrep, you can now use these features without enabling a special setting. ripgrep will fall back to the PCRE2 engine automatically if the regex uses a feature that isn't supported by the Rust regex engine, and search.usePCRE2 is now deprecated. As a reminder, VS Code only supports regexes that are valid in JavaScript, because open editors are still searched using the editor's JavaScript-based search.

**EDIT:** 1 Oct 2019

I found another excellent resource for using this functionality that helped me tremendously. https://dev.to/rfornal/vs-code-search-and-replace-regex-mn2 This discusses how to use the result of the regex in the replace statement, I've been using it gleefully for the last couple of days.

Cheers,
Clinton

Comment: Confusing quote.  If the regex has to be valid in JS, then how can you use advanced regex features that are not available in JS? What's an example of regex that isn't valid in JS that we would have expected to work?